# What does this IMAP command do?

Tags: email, imap

I've received a spam e-mail with this link for one of the buttons:

```
imap://[MY E-MAIL ADDRESS]@mail.btinternet.com:993/fetch>UID>/INBOX>671412#
```

BT is my e-mail provider. What does this link do? Is it simply a mistake by the scammer or is it more malicious? Just automatically generated by the mail website?

To my ignoramus eyes I wonder if it's sending my UID (that is secure?) to another one so they can use it against me?

I did try finding out for myself but quickly lost patience. I expect this is very simple for those of you who have knowledge in this field but I just don't have the time to research.

Comment: Maybe that's not actually what's in the mail. Please check its source code.

Answer (score 0):

The URL probably represents the message itself, and is generated by your mail client rather than the sender. (The "path" part of the URL actually doesn't look like a standard IMAP URL as defined in RFC 2192, so it's probably specific to your mail software.)

The "UID" is an unique ID for a specific message in your IMAP folder; it is assigned when the message is received by the IMAP server, not when it is sent.